# Can'r run curl in nodejs with execFile

Tags: node.js, express, curl

As node `exec` is deprecated, I am trying to migrate my nodejs application to `execFile`, but I am getting problems with a curl call.

this was working with exec:

```
const pab_state = `/usr/bin/curl -d '{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "id": 1, "method": "core.playback.get_state"}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' http://192.168.1.59:6680/mopidy/rpc`
child = exec(pab_state, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
```

Trying to migrate to execFile I am getting issues with escaping quotes:

```
const pab_args = ['-d \'{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "id": 1, "method": "core.playback.get_current_tl_track"}\'',' -H \'Content-Type: application/json\'',' http://192.168.1.59:6680/mopidy/rpc'];

child = execFile("/usr/bin/curl",pab_args, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
{"killed":false,"code":3,"signal":null,"cmd":"/usr/bin/curl -d '{\"jsonrpc\": \"2.0\", \"id\": 1, \"method\": \"core.playback.get_current_tl_track\"}'  -H 'Content-Type: application/json'  http://192.168.1.59:6680/mopidy/rpc"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `options` argument try specifying the shell, like `'/bin/bash'`.

The reason for this is because `execFile`, unlike `exec`, spawns the command directly without first spawning a shell by default. This causes the `curl` command to not execute properly due to the lack of a shell.
The way to get around this is specifying which shell you want to use in the `options` argument.

Here is an example,

```
const { execFile } = require("child_process");

const child = execFile(
  "/usr/bin/curl",
  [
    "-H 'Content-Type: application/json'",
    '-d \'{"title":"foo","body":"bar","userId":"1"}\'',
    "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts "
  ],
  { shell: "/bin/bash" },
  function(error, stdout, stderr) {
    if (error) {
      throw error;
    }
    console.log(stdout);
  }
);
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll give it a try as soon as I am back home, let you know.

Comment: @FabioMarzocca Glad it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue with OP. The cUrl works on terminal but on NodeJS I am getting HTTP 405. I can see what string Exec generates out of this input. Here is the `spawnargs` field in ExecFile log.

```
spawnargs:
       [ '/bin/bash',
         '-c',
         '/usr/bin/curl -v -k -H "Content-Type: application/zip" --data-binary "@/tmp/<filename>.zip" http://<username>:<password>@<host>:8080/path/to/upload?name=<filename>.zip' ],
```

When I run the command above, it just works. I've tried your method but, couldn't see anything different. I've tried lot of things, even checked file permissions but no clue what's happening. I'm suspecting the string formatting in my url and args but not sure. Any idea?

```
let url = `http://<username>:<password>@<host>:8080/path/to/upload?name=${filename}.zip` 
let resp = await execFile(`/usr/bin/curl`,
           [
           `-v -k -H \"Content-Type: application/zip\"`,
           `--data-binary \"@/tmp/${filename}.zip\"`,
           `${url}`
           ],
           {shell:'/bin/bash'},
           async function (error, stdout, stderr) {
           if (error) {
                console.log(`error: ${error.message}`);
                resolve(error);
           }
           if (stderr) {
                console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
                resolve(stderr);
           }
   });
```